# ADODB alternative in .NET

Tags: .net, vb6

i am converting vb6 to .net. And i need to convert this to .net. can i used this with dbdccommand??

```
Public Const CN As String = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=TESTDB;Database=DBA;User Id=DBO;PassWord=dbotest;"

cmd = New ADODB.Command
            rs = New ADODB.Recordset

            With cmd
                .let_ActiveConnection(CN)
                .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
                .CommandText = "s_Servers"
                rs = cmd.Execute
            End With
```

Comment: You are going to use a Command object, a connection object and a datatable object. You will also use SqlParameter object for the sproc paramter. Make sure you begin it with a @.

Comment: SqlConnection I mean

Comment: I'm telling you what the replacement objects are going to be in ado.net.

Comment: sorry i am new this this. could you provide one example

Comment: Just go research ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it.

```
        Dim serverNm As Object
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(CN)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            command.Connection = connection
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.CommandText = "s_Servers"

            connection.Open()
            Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While readerObj.Read
                    serverNm = readerObj("ServerNm")
                End While
            End Using
            connection.Close()
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ADO.NET.

Here are some useful links:

http://www.vbmigration.com/Blog/post/2009/10/Introducing-ADOLibrary-a-revolutionary-approach-to-ADODB-to-ADONET-migration.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971478.aspx

http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/adoplus/employees.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Using cnn as New SqlCommand("Driver={SQL Server};Server=TESTDB;Database=DBA;User Id=DBO;PassWord=dbotest;")
  cnn.Open
    Using cmd as SQLCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      cmd.CommandText = "s_Servers"
      Using da as New SQLDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Using ds as New DataSet
          da.fill(ds)
          ' here's where you figure out how to work with a dataset
          ' you can take it from here
        End Using
      End Using
    End Using
  End Using
```